# Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Server was unable to read request

Tags: webservices, soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex

I have consumed a wsdl in Salesforce.Below is the class which needs to be send as a request

```
public class MEContacts_Request {
        public Long Contact_Type_Association;
        public String Role_Description;
        public String Last_Name;
        public String SF_Ref_Contact_Id;
        public String xxx_Contact_Code;
        public Boolean Is_Primary;
        public String First_Name;
        public DateTime Contact_Date;
        public Boolean Contact;
}
```

Below is the request I tried:

```
wsdltoApexClass.MEContacts_Request objContact;
objContact.xxx_Contact_Code = c.MAFLS_xxx_Ext_Ref_Contact_Id__c;
objContact.contact = true;
```

or

```
wsdltoApexClass.MEContacts_Request objContact;
objContact.xxx_Contact_Code = c.MAFLS_xxx_Ext_Ref_Contact_Id__c;
objContact.contact = true;
objContact.Contact_Type_Association = null;
objContact.Contact_Date = null;
```

I am able to call this web service successfully if i set all the parameters. But as soon as I want to skip some parameters **mainly Date, boolean and Long type**, I get the below error in the callout

> FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed:
>   WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Server was unable to read request.
>   ---> There is an error in XML document (1, 592). ---> Input string was not in a correct format. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=

I am able to **skip tags with String return type** but gets an error as  soon as I skip any tag whose return type is not String.

I tried assigning null values to tags I want to skip, but didn't got any success

I am able to **call the web service with SOAP UI after skipping any tags**. I believe this seems to a problem when WSDL is consumed. Is there any way to call the service successfully without assigning the **date, long and Boolean fields**?

Comment: can you supply the request payload that you're sending ?

Comment: @Ronnie - I have added the request payload

Comment: could you supply a default value on the non-string params? Boolean should never be null should be either true of false. whatever work is being done is probably trying to assign a value and cannot

Comment: Third party  demands thats the tags should be null and can not be defaulted. Do you think the only work around would be to make those String and ask for a new wsdl?

Comment: no it is very likely that the wsdl is fine -  have you tried reformatting the request - from the error - it seems the service doesn't know how to interpret it. again - could be the need for default values on certain types.. for example - converting null to boolean - will fail all the time... it seems to be looking for a false / true string to convert

Comment: What do you suggest? Null values dont work, i chexked that

Comment: attempt it with a default value and see if our response is what you expect consistently

Comment: I cannot send any value. Third pary  expect null value. They are doing some operations based on that. Can't i send null value?

Comment: then maybe on their end they aren't parsing the request properly. your wsdl version is the most recent?

Comment: what about the Is_Primary param? that is never set in the response you send. looking at it again.. can that be sent with a true/false and all others null?

Comment: Wsdl the recent one. They are not even receiving the request. I am not able to send the request from the salesforce.

Comment: Can you share the complete WSDL? Feel free to change the endpoint.